# Git repo is not pre initialized on react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, yarnpkg

I have started learning React JS a few days ago. Previously when I create react app using `npx create-react-app my-app` the react app was created with pre-initialized git. Today I installed windows 10 and when I am creating a new React app it has not pre-initialized git. Is there any problem or any issue that prevents it or it is because of new updates?

**Installed Git, node, npm and yarn version on my windows machine:**

```
Git: 2.33.1
Node: 16.11.1
Npm: 8.1.0
Yarn: 1.22.17
```

[image]

It is no matter to initialize git after creating react app but as I know previously it was pre initialized so I want to know that why this time not happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can happen when you have empty global git credentials.

The workaround is to set it globally (with git config --global user.name user and git config --global user.email user@email.com).

Comment: This is correct. The git global credentials were not set and hence repo was not created. Similar to https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8856